# adyen checkout: How to encrypt card data?

Tags: android, adyen

After collecting user inputs from front end I'm testing backend with java code using adyen android cse project from github. But I do not see any suitable method other then `card.serialize()` that requires public key and generates a encrypted string. Card class has encrypt method but that is private so only works with `card.serialize()` method.

But I want to proceed with checkout. For checkout there's `paymentsRequest.addCardData()` method that requires card info, which I'm able to provide as collecting those info from user but I will get security exception. The other option `paymentsRequest.addEncryptedCardData()` requires encrypted card data but I do not know how to get those encryted fields. Giving test information it will produce `NativeCrypto_SSL_get_certificate => NULL` exception. 
All I get from the cse project is encrypted string.

> So How to checkout successfully using Java codes?

code to checkout:

```
void make_payment(Card card) {

    // Set your X-API-KEY with the API key from the Customer Area.
    Client client = new Client(xApiKey, Environment.TEST);

    final Checkout checkout = new Checkout(client);
    final PaymentsRequest paymentsRequest = new PaymentsRequest();
    paymentsRequest.setMerchantAccount(YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT);
    Amount amount = new Amount();
    amount.setCurrency("EUR");
    amount.setValue(100L);
    paymentsRequest.setAmount(amount);
    /*String encryptedCardNumber = "adyenjs_0_1_18$...encryptedCardNumber";
    String encryptedExpiryMonth = "adyenjs_0_1_18$...encryptedExpiryMonth";
    String encryptedExpiryYear = "adyenjs_0_1_18$...encryptedExpiryYear";
    String encryptedSecurityCode = "adyenjs_0_1_18$...encryptedSecurityCode";
    */
    paymentsRequest.setReference("Your_order_number1");

    paymentsRequest.addCardData(card.getNumber(), 

card.getExpiryMonth(), card.getExpiryYear(), card.getCvc(), card.getCardHolderName());

    paymentsRequest.setReturnUrl("my-app://.Activity");
    PaymentsResponse paymentsResponse = null;
                    try {
                        paymentsResponse = checkout.payments(paymentsRequest);
                    } ...
```

Comment: hmm, it's little bit hard to understated what's the issue here.

As far as I understand there is an issue with CSE library, for that you need to have a public key.

Which Adyen library are you using beside CSE?

Comment: I'm not using other library to encrypt data, only CSE. On gradle dependencies I've added multiple adyen dependencies though. CSE providing that `card.serialize()` method. I want to checkout with minimum required test info.

Comment: Alright, can you please try to use `com.adyen.checkout:cse:3.6.1` and also check this file for an example of how to use it https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-android/blob/master/card-base/src/main/java/com/adyen/checkout/card/CardComponent.java#L168